# Is there any communication protocol that allows time stamping?

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols

I need to write some server client programs where the messages have time stamp  in them.
Is there any protocol which has system time stamp in sent messages?
If not are there any protocols which can be used to solve my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Any protocol has a user-data field can meet your need such as HTTP, AMQP, blabla...